# Use SortableJS/Vue.Draggable with Laravel Livewire

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuedraggable, laravel-livewire

I’m building a Livewire component for a table. I want the rows to be sortable, so I’m trying to implement `VueDraggable` inside my Livewire component.

On my `LivewireTable` component, I define one public property called `$records`.

On the view, I’m using `vue-draggable` like so:

```
<vue-draggable wire:model="records" tag="tbody">
    @foreach($records as $record)
        <tr>
            (...)
        </tr>
    @endforeach
</vue-draggable>
```

When I inspect the Vue component the value is `null`, which means Livewire is not doing what it‘s supposed to.

I’m sure I’m doing something wrong. Can anyone help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which livewire version are you using ? please update it to latest version first.

Comment: I'm using v1.0. But I guess that's the problem since VueJS support was removed during the bump to 1.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Vue JS support was abstracted out in a separate package. You can find it at https://github.com/livewire/vue

Comment: Thanks for your help. It helped, but I think I'm going for a full Vue implementation. I feel Livewire is still too unstable for production environments...

Comment: Happy to help. The problem is that it has very fewer resources in terms of documentation, help, videos, etc which makes it a hard situation to deal with. Being a newer project, it also evolves at a rapid pace, introducing a lot of breaking changes. It's good for small projects or if you are willing to dig into the code to implement a feature you prefer. The mindset change is also huge. I have recently started creating a decently complex app on it. Not putting in client projects yet.